# filter function is not working and giving errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, filter

i am trying to use search filter to search all the element of the table but i am getting this error record.filter is not a function and if removed it then i am getting this error
record.map is not a function. so i don't understand the problem i can't find the solution for this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import React from 'react';

function Read() {
  const [record, setRecord] = useState('');
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then((response) =>{
      console.log(response.data);
      setRecord(response.data);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setSearchTerm(e.target.value) }} placeholder="Search" />
        <table>
         <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role</th>
          </tr> 
          </thead>
          <tbody>   
              {record
              .filter((val) => {
                  if (searchTerm === "") {
                    return val;
                  }
                  else if (
                    val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                    val.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                    val.body.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
                  ) {
                    return val;
                  }
                  return false;
              })
              .map((demo, i)=> {
                return(
                  <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{demo.name}</td>
                  <td>{demo.email}</td>
                  <td>{demo.body}</td>
                </tr>
                )
                })}
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </>
  );
}

export default Read;
```

Comment: `response.data` must not be returning an array, can you paste what the response look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because of rendering issue, sometimes record is just empty value.
you just add `if (!record) return <></>` this code above return.

And you'd better modify your initial value of record to `[]` not `''`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import React from 'react';

function Read() {
  const [record, setRecord] = useState([]); // ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️ HERE!!
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then((response) =>{
      console.log(response.data);
      setRecord(response.data);
    })
  }, [])

  if (!record) return <></> // ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️ HERE!!

  return (
    <>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setSearchTerm(e.target.value) }} placeholder="Search" />
        <table>
         <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role</th>
          </tr> 
          </thead>
          <tbody>   
              {record
              .filter((val) => {
                  if (searchTerm === "") {
                    return val;
                  }
                  else if (
                    val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                    val.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                    val.body.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
                  ) {
                    return val;
                  }
                  return false;
              })
              .map((demo, i)=> {
                return(
                  <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{demo.name}</td>
                  <td>{demo.email}</td>
                  <td>{demo.body}</td>
                </tr>
                )
                })}
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </>
  );
}

export default Read;
```